# Where to ask DPDK leaning and setup tutorial resources

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Where is the "correct" place to ask for learning materials and setup tutorials for DPDK?

I want to learn things like how to set it up on a VM with paravirtualized drivers, and afterwards move to UIO drivers.

I also want to ask things like which VM is is easier to setup: KVM? VMWare? Virtualbox? Xen?

Where is the "right" place to ask these types of questions?

Comment: And if anyone has materials, I'd also be happy to get links :)

Comment: Meta isn't the right place to ask for links either.

Answer (score 7):

None of the Q&A sites on Stack Overflow accept questions that ask for tutorials and other off-site resources. You can try in a chat room if there's one for the topic you're interested in.

Comment: "the Q&A sites on Stack Overflow" Stack Overflow is a single Q&A site. The network is called **Stack Exchange**.